# Music Search Lockscreen Widget History

Tags: music, search, search-history

I have a Nexus 4 running 4.4 (Kitkat) and I use the Music Search widget while listening to the radio on my car.

I have discovered the name of that song or artist I wanted to know many times, but now I realize I can't seem to find my music "search history."

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is this in the (Play) Music App or Settings? I've looked everywhere! Reading thru the Google Help led me no where...

[image: Music Search]

UPDATE: I answered my own question and cleared up the issue, giving credit where due. BTW the picture above was from illustration purposes only, and apparently from a device that has the Sound Search widget history disabled. Sound Search History is not available is some countries.

Comment: The music search widget states that it will `Keep a song identification history, synced across all of your Android devices, so you can purchase a song later` which I have yet to see. According to here it may only be in the US and depend on what version you have. http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/14r6m7/google_releases_updated_sound_search_widget_adds/ Apparently the 'clock' icon will do it http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1p7d0w/ but I don't have that on mine, nor is it on yours. Workarounds are to 'wishlist' the songs, or to screenshot them, which isn't very practical in car

Comment: @RossC Actually you're correct! I was blind. I do see the "clock" icon to the right now on the lockscreen widget. My bad. Since I did not have the widget on my launcher screens, I had no way of getting to the music search widget "history." It appears (just like the reddit post says) the only way to get to it is thru the widget itself (which is stupid).

Comment: BTW the pic above is just a pic I got from... "CBS Interactive"? (apparently) for educational purposes only. I figured people don't know about the Music Search widget. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RossC Write up your answer and I can mark it as correct, for pointing me in the right direction with the reddit link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer was pointed to in the comments by RossC. Thanks! I'm writing my own here since it's been a while and he didn't write a proper answer I could have selected(!).
I did a bit more research to expand on what he found, while also clarifying the original issue which was partly PICNIC...
RossC wrote:

> According to here it may only be in the US and depend on what version you have. 
>   reddit.com/r/Android/comments/14r6m7/… Apparently the 'clock' icon will do it 
>   reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1p7d0w but I don't have that on mine ...

So the second link above gives the answer: On the device one cannot access the Music Search History from anywhere *but* thru the widget's "clock" icon. Since I only had the widget placed in the lockscreen so I did not see the icon while I was actually actively using my phone (unlocked) to look for its history. I can only access the history from the lockscreen widget, that is unless of course I put the widget on one of my panels, which is unnecessary since Google Now can also do music search (just say "what's the song" or similar).

Apparently the Music Search is also unavailable in some countries, so YMMV.

Also, I found out [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sound-search-playlist-in-google-music.html) you **can also access your sound search history on your desktop/laptop** by logging into your Google Account and going to this hidden(?) "auto-playlist" link (I couldn't find anywhere in Play Music site UI):

https://play.google.com/music/listen#/ap/sound-search

Hope this clears a few mysteries regarding Sound Searches and its widget.

Answer (score 1):

My widget has the clock icon at far right which when pressed shows the history. Maybe your screen is not wide enough for it? Their is a music search sync option in your Google account settings in "Accounts & Sync", although I don't think that is the issue. Will keep researching.

Comment: I actually do have the "clock" icon. I hadn't seen it. The issue I was having I guess is that I hadn't noticed it on the lockscreen, **and** I didn't have the widget on one of my launcher screens. Thus, when not in lockscreen, i.e when I was **actually** searching for the history, I had no way of getting to it! Has to be thru the widget!